# Memory keep growing if I load a new dicom file

Tags: three.js, ami.js

[Every time I upload a dicom file, the memory grow up. How can I clean the memory of the old ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcbx4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can see various examples of how to free the memory on the examples code, example on the loader:

```
let loader = new LoadersVolume();
loader.free(); // Free memory
loader = null;
```

Another one:

```
let stackHelper = new HelpersStack();
stackHelper.dispose(); // Free memory
stackHelper = null;
```

I suggest to read the following document to know how garbage collection works on most browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector deletes from the memory everything that is not referenced somewhere.

Having a high use of memory even if you don't you the object anymore means there still a reference to it somewhere. Look for a variable that can still access to your old data, including the 3D scene, the AMI stackHelper, the AMI loader...